# modifying a query to show membership

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have the following query that selects a group of plants that are all in the same genus. It then uses a case statement to determine if any of these plants are in a group of taxonomyIDs.

The final query result contains a list of all plants, and then a column that says 'Yes' or 'No' if the plant is in the group of taxonomyIDs.

I'd like to add to this query. If a plant is in the group of taxonomyIDs, I'd also like to see that ID in the Results. So basically, in addition to showing 'Yes' or 'No', I'd also like to see the taxonomyID.  Maybe a column for each taxonomyID that a plant belongs to?

I tried adding 'fte.taxonomyID' to the first line, but it can't find that column.

```
    SELECT  PlantTypeID ,
        displayName ,
        displayType ,
        Genus = 2016 ,
        member = CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                                    FROM    FT_SPECIES fte
                                    WHERE   fte.TypeID = dtu.PlantTypeID
                                            AND fte.taxonomyID IN ( 1994327868,
                                                              1994327869,
                                                              1994327870,
                                                              1994327871,
                                                              1994327877,
                                                              1994327878,
                                                              1994327879,
                                                              1994327880 ) )
                      THEN 'YES'
                      ELSE 'NO'
                 END
FROM    DT_Plant_USERS AS dtu
WHERE   dtu.Genus = 2016
ORDER BY member DESC ;
```

Comment: Just change your case statement a bit: `fte.taxonomyID IN (1994327868,1994327869,1994327870,1994327871,
                             1994327877,1994327878,1994327879,1994327880)
) THEN 'YES'+ fte.taxonomyID ELSE 'NO' END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you need to look up `taxonomyID` in the `FT_Species` table.  This suggests using an explicit `join` instead of a nested `select`:

```
SELECT PlantTypeID, displayName, displayType, 2016 as Genus,
       fs.TaxonomyId,
       (case when fs.TypeId is not NULL then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as member
FROM DT_Plant_USERS dtu left outer join
     FT_Species fs
     on fs.TypeId = dtu.PlantTyeId and
        fte.taxonomyID IN (1994327868, 1994327869, 1994327870, 1994327871,
                           1994327877, 1994327878, 1994327879, 1994327880)
WHERE dtu.Genus = 2016
ORDER BY member DESC;
```

This query could produce duplicate values, when there is more than one row in `FT_Speciies` for a given `TypeId`.  If this is a problem, then you might need to add a `group by`.

EDIT:

If you wanted to know if the plant was in *all* the ids, then you would need an aggregation and some more logic.  The following counts the number of matching taxonomies and makes sure that all 8 are present:

```
SELECT PlantTypeID, displayName, displayType, 2016 as Genus,
       (case when 8 =
                  count(distinct case when fte.taxonomyID IN (1994327868, 1994327869, 1994327870, 1994327871,
                                                   1994327877, 1994327878, 1994327879, 1994327880
                                                  ) 
                                      then fte.taxonomyId
                                 end)
              then 'ALL' else 'NOT-ALL'
        end) as member
FROM DT_Plant_USERS dtu left outer join
     FT_Species fs
     on fs.TypeId = dtu.PlantTyeId and
        fte.taxonomyID IN (1994327868, 1994327869, 1994327870, 1994327871,
                           1994327877, 1994327878, 1994327879, 1994327880)
WHERE dtu.Genus = 2016
GROUP BY PlantTypeID, displayName, displayType
ORDER BY member DESC;
```

Comment: What if I needed to show a yes/no column that stated whether or not the plant was in ALL of the taxonomyIDs?   Thanks